# Why request doesn't create file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created an php file submit_request.php with following code:

```
$tx_hash =  $_POST['tx_hash'];
$home-address =  $_POST['home-address'];
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$file = fopen($tx_hash, 'w');
fwrite($file, $home-address);
fwrite($file, $email);
fwrite($file, $tx_hash);
fclose($file);
```

So this file is called in my index.html file under this code:

```
$.ajax ({
type: 'POST',
url: 'submit_request.php?tx_hash=document.getElementById("tx-
hash").value&home-address=document.getElementById("home-
address").value&email=document.getElementById("email").value',
success: function(data){

}

});
```

But it don't create the file like excepted after calling. Why? Please give me an explanation how to get this code working ;)

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Please check the value of $tx_hash variable, then check the path is correct ?  fopen http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: the url data has `document.getElementById` statements that are not escaped so their value is not being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending data separately. I have made some changes in variable names. Please try the below code,

```
     <?php
       $tx_hash =  $_POST['tx_hash'];
       $home_address =  $_POST['home_address'];
       $email =  $_POST['email'];
       $file = fopen($tx_hash, 'w');
       fwrite($file, $home_address);
       fwrite($file, $email);
       fwrite($file, $tx_hash);
       fclose($file);
```

Your Ajax code here

```
       $.ajax ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'submit_request.php',
          data: {
             tx_hash:document.getElementById("tx_hash").value,
             home_address:document.getElementById("home_address").value,
             email:document.getElementById("email").value
           },
          success: function(data){

          }
       });
```

Comment: I just checked the questions you posted. If someone helped & if you think it worked for you, then please feel free to accept the answer so that it will be helpful for future reference for other SO users. This is how SO works. Please check, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes to actually include the values of the HTML elements otherwise you are sending an incorrect string with `document.getElementById(...)` as part of the request

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'submit_request.php?tx_hash='+document.getElementById("tx-hash").value+'&home-address='+document.getElementById("home-address").value+'&email='+document.getElementById("email").value,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data)
    }

});
```